# Create multi-index from multiple dataframes in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Suppose I have

```py
l1 = [[1,2], [3,4], [5,6]]
l2 = [[10,20], [30, 40], [50, 60]]

df1 = pd.DataFrame(l1)
df2 = pd.DataFrame(l2)

df1.index = ["t1", "t2", "t3"]
df2.index = ["t1", "t2", "t3"]
df1.columns = ["A", "B"]
df2.columns = ["A", "B"]

# such that
print(df1)
    A  B
t1  1  2
t2  3  4
t3  5  6

print(df2)
     A   B
t1  10  20
t2  30  40
t3  50  60

# How do I easily create a multi-index dataframe df3 with the structure

print(df3)
      df1 df2
t1
   A  1   10
   B  2   20
t2
   A  3   30
   B  4   40
t3
   A  5   50
   B  6   60
```

so that the multi-indexes are [t1, t2, t3], [A, B] and the columns are [df1, df2]?

I know you can create multi-indexes through pd.MultiIndex or other methods but I want a simple solution where you can create it directly from the 2/multiple dataframes directly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First [`concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) and then [`stack`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html):

```
out = pd.concat([df1, df2], keys=['df1', 'df2'], axis=1).stack()
```

Output:

```
      df1  df2
t1 A    1   10
   B    2   20
t2 A    3   30
   B    4   40
t3 A    5   50
   B    6   60
```

Answer (score 1):

You will need to use a combination of reshaping & concatenation.

- `df.stack` to reshaped each DataFrame such that its columns become a second level of rows against your row index. This will turn each `DataFrame` into a longer `Series`.
- `pd.concat` to concatenate these newly reshaped `Series` together.

```py
all_dfs = [df1, df2]
out_df = (
    pd.concat([d.stack() for d in all_dfs], axis='columns')
    # the below code spruces up the column names
    .rename(columns=lambda v: v+1)
    .add_prefix('df')
)

print(out_df)
      df1  df2
t1 A    1   10
   B    2   20
t2 A    3   30
   B    4   40
t3 A    5   50
   B    6   60
```